# Avoiding snails around potted greenery

Tags: pressure, mass, everyday-life, biology, adhesion

I am not sure how a snail "sticks" to surfaces e.g. plastic pot or stone. I suspect that it produces mucus, which then adheres with molecular forces.

I would like to know, how does the contact surface between the snail and the surface maximizes the force with which the snail is attached to a surface.

Comment: a ring of salt around the pot would stop them

Comment: Another simple gardeners' solution is to rub a thin layer of petroleum jelly around the rim of the pot. I'm not sure this questions belongs on S.E. Physics though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Comment: It could be good physical problem if you include some sketch and explanation which phenomena you think should occur there and formulate what exacly is ur question

Comment: @Vid I will include a picture....

Comment: I think it is salvaged, if we focus on explaining why would it or would not work

Comment: I'd say it's still off-topic, for being then either trap engineering and/or problem specific. I edited it, removing this part, and voting to reopen (of course my edit can be rolled back).

Comment: Trap part: "I had an idea about snail trap (https://i.stack.imgur.com/78UCB.jpg). I was wondering if placing a plastic ring in a form of a brush around a pot with needles pointing down would serve the purpose. Using very tiny spaced needles (i.e. low density per cm$^2$) would force the hungry snail to fall down due to a small contact area, right? (See picture). What are the physics principles behind this trap."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.